# Apache web server test

Tags: php, web-services, apache

How i can test a web server that is working fine ? i have the apache to hosting my php code. i would like to test if my server is good in order to publish my php web services.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: To what extent do you need to "test" your server?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to create a page with the following code:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

That should give you a test page with all the info related to php. Not only will it show you that php is working it'll give you a list of options you've selected(in case you missed anything).